# why is my cmd giving error that it cannot find node-modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, node-modules

[image] Here is my command prompt.

Is it necessary to have the module folder and the folder in which I am keeping the code together??

Comment: are you sure, this file exits.  maybe typos or it's extension is js

Comment: you can run js apps withouts node_module there, you have to run `npm install` to get your app running.

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to be running index.js? Maybe it's server.js

Answer (score 1):

It can't find the module named `index` in the current path. check you package.json file under the script item, you should see a parameter with the following value: "start":"node index". make sure index is the file with you javascript code, i.e. make sure its `node index.js`